# Customizing HTML Editor Quicktags button to open a dialog for choosing insert options

Tags: posts, editor, quicktag

I am looking for adding custom quicktag buttons, that would allow me to display a intermediary dialog before inserting the code.

### Situation

1. Clicking a quicktag button opens a dialog or thickbox modal window.
2. Opened dialog displays some options on the class, etc and an Insert button.
3. Clicking "Insert" button inserts the code.

### Background

To add an quicktags button, we would use

```
edButtons[ edButtonsLength+ ] = new edButton(
    'ed_mybutton' , 'Insert button', '<div class="class-name">', '</div>'
);
////
edHTML += '<input type="button" value="Insert custom code" id="ed_my_button" class="ed_button" onclick="edInsertTag( edCanvas, edButtonLength_t + 1)" title="Insert code" />';
```

Now how can i bypass the button to open a dialog(or thickbox modal) instead?

I can add a button without defining it, like

```
edHTML += '<input type="button" value="Insert custom code" id="ed_my_button" class="ed_button" onclick="customFunction()" title="Insert code" />';
// and
var customFunction = function() {
   openURL = '<?php admin_url() ?>admin-ajax.php?action="insertCodeAction&TB_iframe=true';
   tb_show( 'Insert custom code', openURL );
};
```

Please share your wisdom. Thanks in advance.

PS: doing this with TinyMCE is relatively easy, i wonder how do i do that with HTML quicktags. :)

Comment: I haven't any idea to add a modal, open a dialog box, bit a solution to replace code to publish as context and add css class, maybe this helps you a little bid. You find the code here: https://github.com/bueltge/AddQuicktag/blob/master/js/add-quicktags.dev.js#L150

Answer (score 1):

According to the Codex, you can't do this directly through the API. However, you can do it by using your own quicktags.js file as shown below.

```
function sample_load_admin_scripts()
{
  if ( is_admin() ) {
    wp_deregister_script('quicktags');
    wp_register_script('quicktags', ("/path/to/your/quicktags.js"), false, '', true);
  }
}

if (is_admin()) {
  add_action('init', sample_load_admin_scripts);
}
```

Then just add Javascript to do your work. The formatting is relatively easy, but since you know how to do everything with TinyMCE I'm not going to go into that. [Go get a quicktags.js file of your own here.](http://alexking.org/projects/js-quicktags)

Comment: this is not giving me output